# How to write an AHK script that uses a shortcut to close PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, autohotkey, hotkeys

I've known that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> could close PowerShell, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is already in use for me, I want to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>, how to achieve that in AHK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script enables using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close PowerShell:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe powershell.exe
  !F4::
  ^d::WinClose
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
!F4::Send !{Space}C
```

Or if you want something specific to PowerShell, then you can use this:

```
!F4::WinClose ahk_exe powershell.exe
```

Or this:

```
!F4::WinKill ahk_exe powershell.exe
```

The difference between `WinClose` and `WinKill` is that, for example, when editing a file in Notepad without saving, `WinKill` will close it without asking to save and `WinClose` will ask.